# Can using black glue coating on an umbrella block 99.99% of UV-A and UV-B radiations?

Tags: physics, healthcare

I read on https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07XP321LY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 ([mirror](http://archive.is/wip/GnjGX)):

> Black glue umbrella is the newer version sun umbrella instead of silver glue umbrella. **Our XUYAO sun umbrellas are coated with triple (3x) black glue, providing UPF 50+ highest UV protection, blocking UV-A 99.99%, blocking UV-B 99.99%**. And the black glue are coated inside where is safe from rain-washing, providing lifetime UV protection.

Can using black glue coating on an umbrella block 99.99% of UV-A and UV-B radiations?

I couldn't find anything when searching for "glue coating".

Comment: Of course you will still get a substantial dose (much greater than 0.001% of the direct radiaton) from rays reflected from the ground and nearby objects. To a first approximation you get the same proportion of the UV as you do the visible light (assuming no filters that block UV but not visible light). So unless you sit in a blacked-out tent the coating makes very little practical difference.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: [citation-needed]

Comment: @Oddthinking https://www.sunsmart.com.au/skin-cancer/myths-that-lead-to-skin-cancer https://www.abc.net.au/health/thepulse/stories/2015/01/19/4158212.htm https://www.cancer.org/healthy/be-safe-in-sun/uv-protection.html

Comment: @Oddthinking another reference regarding reflective UV: https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/article-abstract/2597893

Comment: @PaulJohnson thanks Paul, I'm only considering direct UV when computing the percentage of blocked UV

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - **YES**

More complicated answer - anything, with enough layers can block UV rays to such extent.
UV are waves. 315- 399 nm for a UVA and 280-314 nm and UVB in wavelenght.  So using a losesly knit clothes leaves the opening for the wavelength to go through. Stacking layers on top of each other make the opening smaller and smaller. [WHO Individual protection against UV clothing](https://www.who.int/uv/faq/protect/en/index6.html)

Most complicated answer - it's not the matter of  material but it's color. 
Difference beetwen silver and black glue is just hue. The darker the hue (of anything beetwen you and sun) the more UV rays are absorbed.
Darker the color the more wavelentght is absorbed and not bounced back. [Which color reflect more light](https://sciencing.com/colors-reflect-light-8398645.html)

There is a diffrence beetwen "Blocking" and "absorbing" but in the marketing world what is important is how to sell you the final amount that get to your skin.

There is some miscomunication in the text you quote, as "what is silver glue umbrella"? Do they compare to single sheet of fabric single coating with silver glue or a "sandwich" umbrella where you have two sheets of material and glue beetwen them (and such umbrellas provide 100% UV).

Additional info

> Unfortunately, an international standard for the concept of the UPF has not been developed yet.

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: You haven't shown that hue is relevant. You haven't shown that this umbrella (or any umbrella) reaches 99.99% (or even UPF 50+) This isn't an answer.

Comment: Darker colours only mean that more of the _visible_ wavelength is absorbed.  That link you've provided doesn't suggest anything about light outside of the visible spectrum, where UV radiation falls.

Comment: Hue is definitely a red herring, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_oxide#UV_absorber is incredibly common in sunscreen and white in the visible spectrum.
Reflectiveness should be perfectly fine for blocking, the concern should be penetration through the fabric, not absorbtion vs. reflection.

Comment: Yeah, *visible* hue has absolutely sod-all to do with *ultraviolet* absorption or lack thereof. It's theoretically possible to have a material that's entirely black and opaque to the visual spectrum yet perfectly translucent to UV, and vice versa.